# CSS masonry problems

Tags: css, masonry

I've recently discovered a neat way to do a masonry layout using columns, as found here: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/. I've expanded on this layout by adding an overlay with text to each item upon hover. This works pretty well except for 2 problems:

1. The overlay is slightly larger than the image at the bottom. This persists even when different images are used.
2. The transitions do not work; the hover effect displays and hides abruptly.

Some explanations regarding my code:

1. I've added `margin: 0; border:0; padding:0` to the entire document in an attempt to prevent problems just like this one, to no avail. `.item` has `margin: 0 0 20px` to provide vertical spacing between each item.
2. Because `.item-overlay` requires `position:absolute` to work, and `position:absolute` requires the parent element to be positioned, I've added `position:relative` to `.item`. This doesn't affect anything beyond allowing the overlay to show up correctly, as far as I can tell.
3. `.item-overlay` uses `display:flex` to vertically and horizontally centralise its content, but this shouldn't affect the layout.

Could someone help me figure out what's wrong with the code? JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nattanyz/sfn47me9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align: top` on the `img` and transition `opacity` instead of `display`

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: honeydew;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51, 0.6);
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.6);
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}

.item:hover .item-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.project-img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.project-name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.project-category {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
      <div class="item-overlay">
        <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
        <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
      <div class="item-overlay">
        <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
        <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
      <div class="item-overlay">
        <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
        <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
      <div class="item-overlay">
        <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
        <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
      <div class="item-overlay">
        <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
        <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
      <div class="item-overlay">
        <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
        <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
      <div class="item-overlay">
        <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
        <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! `vertical-align:top` fixed it. Why didn't the original code work without it, though?

Comment: An image is treated as inline content, and there is space at the bottom of inline content for the little trails on characters (like p,j,q,etc). `vertical-align: top` or `display: block` will remove that space. @NatTan

Answer (score 0):

> 1. The overlay is slightly larger than the image at the bottom. This persists even when different images are used.

The problem is on the image itself, it has height smaller than the container. Try to put some `background-color` on the container, you will see that the overlay height is equal with it's parent.

> 2. The transitions do not work; the hover effect displays and hides abruptly.

You cannot implements transition on the css `display`, other alternative would be using `opacity`. I modified your code, please try.

```css
html {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing:inherit;
}

body {
 background-color:honeydew;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 120%;
 color: #333;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 80vw;
 max-width:1200px;
 margin: auto;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
 column-count: 3;
 column-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
 display:block;
 margin: 0 0 20px;
 border:0;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
  background-color: black;
}

.item-overlay {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.6);
 color:white;
 opacity:0;
 transition:300ms ease opacity;
  
  display: flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
}

.item:hover .item-overlay {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.6);
}

.project-img {
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 border:0;
 padding:0;
}

.project-name {
 font-weight:bold;
}

.project-category {
 font-size:0.75em;
 text-transform:uppercase;
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
   <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/>
   <div class="item-overlay">
    <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
    <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/>
   <div class="item-overlay">
    <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
    <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/>
   <div class="item-overlay">
    <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
    <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/>
   <div class="item-overlay">
    <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
    <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/>
   <div class="item-overlay">
    <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
    <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/>
   <div class="item-overlay">
    <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
    <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="project-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/>
   <div class="item-overlay">
    <p class="project-name">Project Name</p>
    <p class="project-category">Commercial</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Hmm, why is the image smaller than the container though? Shouldn't height be auto by default?

Comment: because the width is set as `100%`, the height scaled automatically following the ratio, so the image will be in proportional size